# Undefined Local Variable Error

Tags: ruby

Keep getting an Undefined Local Variable error when I run the code below. The problem seems to stem from something having to do with my gets.chomp.
I've included the entire program so that there is a little bit of context. The problem seems to arise from line 16 but I get the same error from the next gets.chomp even if I remove the first one.

```
def test()
  score = 0
  def scorekeeper(input, answer)
  if input == answer
      puts "Correct!"
      score += 10
      puts score
  else
      puts "incorrect :("
  end
  end

  puts "Welcome to Virtual Math Test V1.0.0"
  sleep 0.7
  puts "What is Your Name?"
  gets.chomp = username

  puts "Question 1) \n 24 * 24"
  gets.chomp = ans1
  scorekeeper(ans1, 24 * 24)
  system "clear"

  puts "Question 2) \n 28 / 4"
  gets.chomp = ans2
  scorekeeper(ans2, 28 / 4)
  system "clear"

  puts "Question 3) \n 754 + 222"
  gets.chomp = ans3
  scorekeeper(ans3, 976)
  system "clear"

  puts "Well Done!"
  puts "#{username} scored #{score} points out of 30!"
  sleep 0.4
  puts "do you want to take the test again? y/n"
  gets.chomp.downcase = repeatyn

  if repeatyn == y || yes
      test()
  else
      abort("Ok, See you later #{username}!")
  end
end

test()
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's `username = gets.chomp` not `gets.chomp = username`

Comment: The order matters: `gets.chomp = username` means 'set `gets.chomp` to the value of `username` (which doesn't exist)'. Try `username = gets.chomp` (and so on for the other examples).

Comment: When you report error messages please provide the full message (other than the backtrace, unless relevant) and the line where it occurred (which you did provide). The information that you omitted is the local variable or method that is undefined, which is included in the message: `username`, which more-or-less pinpoints the problem. Had the right side of the offending message been, say "cat", the error message would have been 'NoMethodError: undefined method 'chomp=' for "cat\n":String', as `chomp =` is read by Ruby as the method `chomp=`, which is not defined. Error messages deserve respect!

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Take out everything that doesn't demonstrate the problem. When you've done that the odds are good at that point you'll see what is wrong. Including the entire code doesn't help, context or not, but instead it clutters and makes us look through stuff that doesn't matter, which only slows our ability to help you. Instead, present only what's absolutely necessary, which helps us help you and then helps us help others.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignments are the wrong way round, the following

```
gets.chomp = username
gets.chomp = ans1
gets.chomp = ans2
gets.chomp = ans3
gets.chomp.downcase = repeatyn
```

should be rewritten as:

```
username = gets.chomp
ans1 = gets.chomp
ans2 = gets.chomp
ans3 = gets.chomp
repeatyn = gets.chomp.downcase
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks, dude. That was a brain dead move on my part.